# Configure not to require the Range Header?

Tags: windows, wsus, bits

I am trying to get my WSUS server to download patches through a proxy.

The proxy screws up the http header. BITS requires the range header.

Is there a way to get BITS not to require the range header? I don't have access to the proxies, but I need these patches to download.

Edit:

WSUS is on Server 2012

From the answers below I tried this (in powershell, from [here](http://learn-powershell.net/2013/07/07/use-the-wsus-api-and-powershell-to-query-the-susdb-database/)):

```
Add-Type -Path "$Env:ProgramFiles\Update Services\Api\Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.dll"    
$Wsus = [Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.AdminProxy]::GetUpdateServer("dc1",$False,80)

$db = $wsus.GetDatabaseConfiguration().CreateConnection()
$db.executecommandnoresult('USE SUSDB update tbConfigurationC set BitsDownloadPriorityForeground=1')
```

This did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there is any way for BITS to work without the range header. Your best option is to have your proxy configured to support the range request feature.

Since you said that you don't have access to the proxies, you could try setting BITS to work in foreground mode:

Click **Start**, click **Run**, type one of the following commands, and then click **OK**.

1. If you are using WSUS 2.0 with a MSDE or WMSDE database that was created by a default WSUS installation, type the following command:

   `%programfiles%\Update Services\tools\osql\osql.exe -S %Computername%\WSUS -E -b -n -Q "USE SUSDB update tbConfigurationC set BitsDownloadPriorityForeground=1`
   If you configured WSUS 2.0 to use an existing installation of Microsoft SQL Server, type the following command:

   `%programfiles%\Update Services\tools\osql\osql.exe" -S %Computername% -E -b -n -Q "USE SUSDB update tbConfigurationC set BitsDownloadPriorityForeground=1"`
   If you are using WSUS 3.0 with a Windows Internal Database that was created by a default WSUS installation, type the following command:
   `%programfiles%\Update Services\Setup\ExecuteSQL.exe -S %Computername%\MICROSOFT##SSEE -d "SUSDB" -Q "update tbConfigurationC set BitsDownloadPriorityForeground=1"`
   If you configured WSUS 3.0 to use an existing installation of SQL Server, type the following command:
   `%programfiles%\Update Services\Setup\ExecuteSQL.exe -S %Computername% -d "SUSDB" -Q "update tbConfigurationC set BitsDownloadPriorityForeground=1"`
2. Restart the Update Services service. To do this, follow these steps:
   Click Start, click Run, type services.msc, and then click OK.
   In the Services dialog box, right-click Update Services, and then click Restart.

Reference Microsoft [KB 922330](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/922330).

Comment: I think the correct answer to this was stated first, you need to change the proxy :(

Comment: There are no `osql.exe` or `executesql.exe` on my system. Where can I find them?